# Alternatives to work with .xlsx files?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't have Excel'07 installed on my machine, but I need to work with .xlsx files.

Excel'03 has a compatibility pack, but I could only open xslx files, not being able to save or create them.

Do you know any free alternatives to work with .xlsx ?

Comment: Once you import the xlsx file, change it and store it as xls. Why do you want to store it as xlsx again?

Comment: I guess information here is outdated. Iused to both read and save to XLSX using Compatibiltiy Pack and Excel 2003 or XP. So perhaps "not being able to save" was caused to either some specific spreadsheet content or to early buggy version of MS Compatibility Conversion Pack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/) Calc** works opens .xlsx files and works with them just fine, only it can't save as .xlsx as well - you'd need to save as .xls or .xml (Excel 2003 XML). But generally there should be no problem saving as .xls/.xml unless you are using some very unique Excel 2007 features that aren't available in older versions.

Comment: Vanilla Calc does not. However there were InfraResource's OpenOffice Pro, which could. I suspect they took XLSX save routine from Go-OO project, that later served as core for LibreOffice. But i never tried Go-OO, so i cannot be sure. OOoPro stalled as 3.3.0 http://i-rs.ru/download and LibreOffice has problems with reading some kinds of XLSX XML-SS files, that vanilla OOo reads fine. Thus, no clear winner here :-)

Answer (score 3):

Google Docs supposedly can work with .xlsx now

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/06/02/google-docs-adds-docx-and-xlsx-support/

Edit:  I just tested it out, you can import the .xlsx and work with it, but google docs can't save as xlsx yet, so, you'd need to export it back out as xls or other supported format.  Still, it is a free option that will let you work with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Office tells to support XLSX but what about their compatibiltiy ("supports: write: incomplete") or Windows support (their main target is Linux) i cannot say, did not tried.

http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/doc/sect-file-formats.shtml

---

Microsoft Works version 9 (also known as Microsoft Works 2007) also is claimed to support reading and writing XLSX files.
Though its copy, if not for some leftovers, can hardly be purchased, as the product was obsoleted and replaced by Office Starters (provided to computer OEMs, not to users themselves). However such a product did existed.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940005